# Android device camera is not opening, after allowing system permission with Ionic 3

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic3, android-7.0-nougat

I wanted to use camera plugin in my app. I requested camera permission, but after allowing camera is not opening

**Trying it on Following device**
 - Moto g4 plus
   with android version 7.0

**Following is Ionic info**

cli packages: (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1

**global packages:**
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

**local packages:**
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

**System:**
    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.11.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

**Environment Variables:**
    ANDROID_HOME : C:\android-sdk-win

**Misc:**
    backend : pro

**Following is my code**

openCamera(){

```
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
        result => {
            alert(result.hasPermission);
            if(!result.hasPermission) {
                this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
                .then( cam => {
                    alert('permission result '+ JSON.stringify(cam) );
                    this.capturingPicture();
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    alert('permission error occured '+ JSON.stringify(error) );
                });
            } else {
                this.capturingPicture();
            }
        },
        err => {
            this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA); 
        });
}
```

capturingPicture function alert is displaying but device camera is not opening.

```
capturingPicture(){
    alert('capturingPicture');

    const options: CameraOptions = {
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        quality : 75, 
                   destinationType : this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
                   sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
                  allowEdit : true,
                  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                  targetWidth: 300,
                  targetHeight: 300,
                 saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        alert('image data => '+ imageData);
    }, (err) => {
        // Handle error
        alert('get picture error => '+ err);
    });
}
```

As per documentation, wrote code, but still not getting whether it is code/plugin/verions/OS etc issue.
Please guide me with this.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command to install camera in ionic 3

> npm install --save @ionic-native/camera@4